# Kinetic energy in high speed frame

Tags: special-relativity

I am just learning special relativity,so i have a very vague understanding and have lot of doubts in mind. I am expressing a basic doubt of mine which will then lead to my actual question.

Suppose a spaceship has left earth with a very high velocity(comparable to the speed of light). There is a ball of mass $m$ and an austronaut in the spaceship. If the ball starts moving with $v$ velocity(from the perspective of astronaut), will the kinetic energy measured by astronaut $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ or $(m-m_0)c^2$? I am confused by this since one is newtonian kinetic energy formula and the other one is einsteinian. So,i don't know which one to follow. Furthermore, what will be the kinetic energy of the ball as seen by a person on earth?

My actual doubt is the photoelectric effect we learn. The equation is $hf=hf_0+\frac{1}{2}mv^2$. My question is: "Is this equation valid for only ground frame observers? Or this is valid for high speed aircraft as well?". Since $h$ and frequencies remain constant, how much velocity of electron ejected will be measured by an astronaut in spaceship?

Relativity is a bit hard for me to understand. So i will be very grateful if someone kindly enlightens me with proper concepts.

Comment: *I don't know which one to follow.* You said that one is Newtonian and one is Einsteinian. And you know that Einstein discovered Special Relativity.

Comment: That said, modern physicists do not write kinetic energy in terms of $m$ and $m_0$. They no longer use the obsolete concept of “relativistic mass”, and they now use $m$ to mean the Lorentz-invariant mass (which happens to also be the rest mass). They write $K=(\gamma-1)mc^2$ where $\gamma\equiv\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}$ is the “Lorentz factor” for speed $v$. They might also write $K=E-E_0$ where $E=\gamma mc^2$ is the relativistic energy and $E_0=mc^2$ is the rest energy.

Comment: What is "measured" (in the real world) is conceptually different from what is "calculated" using various proposed formulas involving other measured quantities. So, the question really should be: Is what is "measured" properly predicted by (say) the Newtonian formula or the Einsteinian formula?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a spaceship has left earth with velocity 1 km/s. There is a ball of mass m and an astronaut in the spaceship.

When that rocket pushed the ball with force F, while the ball moved a distance d, the ball gained kinetic energy exactly F*d, which is approximately $1/2*  mv^2$

Let's say the astronaut pushes the ball with force 1 N for time 1 s, the ball gains energy 1 N * 1001 m. (Astronaut's body moves 1000 m during one second, the hand pushing the ball moves one meter more)

From the perspective of the astronaut, the kinetic energy of the ball increased by 1N * 1m = 1J.

Next the pushed ball hits an inelastic spaceship wall making a dent on it. The energy lost by ball and gained by wall is 1 J according to astronaut and 1001 J  according to a person on earth. The energy used to make the dent is 1 J according to everyone.

And next the same astronaut shoots a photon, that hits an atom, that breaks.

This "shooting a photon" is done by taking a photon with no energy and giving it energy by pushing it by force F while the photon moves distance d. That d is different for astronaut and for a person on earth. So energy and frequency are different for those people.

So then finally the photon pushes the atom with force F while the atom moves distance d. Change of energy of photon and atom is F*d, where d is different for the astronaut and for a person on earth.

The energy that the photon uses to push the atom is different for different people, while the energy that the photon uses to break the atom is the same for different people.